# Error while getting the input from the div id

Tags: javascript, html

I need to create a web page as the picture show below

[image: First Screen]

[image: Screen for entering the feedback]
[image: Screen after clicking the add feedback button]
[image: Screen after clicking view feedback button]

And here is my html and Javascript for the same

```js
var arrayForStoring = [];
function addFeedback(){
    arrayForStoring.push(document.getElementById("feedback").value);
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "<h2>" + "Feedback Details " + "</h2>"+"<br>" +"Successfully Added Feedback Details!";
    document.getElementById("feedback").value = "";
}

function displayFeedback(){
    var i = 1;
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "";
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML += "<h2>" + "Feedback Details " + "</h2>"+"<br>";
    for (var element in arrayForStoring) {
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML += "Feedback " + i++ + "<br>" + arrayForStoring[element] + "<br>";
    }
    arrayForStoring = [];
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
    <script src="script.js" type="text/javascript"> </script>
  </head>
  <body> 
    
    <h2>Feedback for the ART OF LIVING session</h2>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Enter the Feedback:</td>
            <td>
                <textarea id = "feedback" name = "textarea"></textarea>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td>
                <input type = "button" id = "create" value = "Add Feedback"
                onclick = "addFeedback();">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td>
                <input type = "button" id = "view" value = "View Feedback"
                onclick = "displayFeedback();">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <div id="result"></div>
    <script src = "script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

But when I click on evaluate on my study platform it shows
**Error while getting the input from the div id 'result'**

I dont know what is the actual problem. If someone help me it will be very much great. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove `<br>` element from
`document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "<h2>" + "Feedback Details " + "</h2>"+"<br>" +"Successfully Added Feedback Details!";` in both addFeedback and displayFeedback methods